# Xamarin App doesn't communicate with WebApi

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I created Microsoft MVC WebApi for managining users accounts -  login, register account ......

I have this WebApi on Computer in my local network on `http://192.168.0.185`

When I open this "site" on my Android Phone - Google Chrome (`http://192.168.0.185/Token`, `http://192.168.0.185/api/login`) I show that this WebApi is working.

Now, I am trying to attempt this WebApi from Xamarin.Forms (deployed on Android). When I Click on the submit button (it should send the request to the server) it seems that nothing happened (after some time the app is frozen). Also when I am trying to debug this code it also seems that nothing happened :(

there is my method: (`apiBaseUri = http://192.168.0.185`)

```
private async  Task<string> GetAPIToken(string userName, string password, string apiBaseUri) {

    JObject jObject = null;
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUri);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", userName),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
            });

            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("/Token", formContent);

            var responseJson = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            jObject = JObject.Parse(responseJson);

        }           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return jObject.GetValue("access_token").ToString();
}
```

The catch block doesn't catch any error ...

//EDITED:

This is my handler for method:

```
loginButton.Clicked += OnLoginButtonClicked;
```

and this is how the method is called:

```
async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e    ) {

    try {
        var token = GetAPIToken(usernameEntry.Text, passwordEntry.Text, "http://192.168.0.185").Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    App.IsUserLoggedIn = true;
    Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new MainPage(), this);
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

Now I am getting this error and the screen is frozen.
[image: Getting this error in Visual studio]

Comment: Sounds like you are mixing sync and async code higher up the stack (deadlock). Show how the above function is called.

Comment: I couldn't find any problem with your posted code and as you said you get no exception in here, so I agree with Nkosi, please show how this `GetAPIToken` task is called.

Comment: hello :) I added aditional information :)

Comment: @user1912372 next time include `@` when directing your comment to someone. I only noticed your update after the post was closed. The blocking call `GetAPIToken(...).Result` in the event handler is what is causing your problem (deadlock). Use an `await` there instead and that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are mixing sync and async code higher up the stack (deadlock).

The blocking call `GetAPIToken(...).Result` in the event handler is what is causing your problem (deadlock). Use an `await` there instead and that should fix it.

```
async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e    ) {

    try {
        var token = await GetAPIToken(usernameEntry.Text, passwordEntry.Text, "http://192.168.0.185");
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

    App.IsUserLoggedIn = true;
    Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new MainPage(), this);
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```